# encontrar una palabra u otra en excel bva

Tags: excel, vba, macros, microsoft-office, formulas

mi pregunta es la siguiente espero que me pueda dar a entender, tengo una base de datos en excel y lo que quiero es a través de vba encontrar cual es la primera vez que aparece una palabra en una celda de una columna, es una cadena larga de texto y quiero saber de entre las palabras "perro" "gato" "liebre" aparece primero, estas palabras se encuentran en medio de una cadena de texto larga con muchas otras palabras y aparecen de forma aleatoria, es decir no llevan un orden, quiero a traves de vba que encuentre que valor que aparece primero y lo ponga en otra celda.

He intentado por mi cuenta muchas formulas y lineas de codigo y no consigo mas que errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que ocupas es saber que palabra se encuentra en el texto de una celda puedes realizar la siguiente función:

```
Function buscarPrimeraPalabra(texto As String) As String
buscarPrimeraPalabra = ""
posicion = 0

' Buscar "perro" en el texto
posicionPerro = InStr(texto, "perro")

' Si se encontró "perro" en el texto y es la primera palabra que aparece, asignar a buscarPrimeraPalabra y a posicion
If posicionPerro > 0 Then
    If posicion = 0 Or posicionPerro < posicion Then
        buscarPrimeraPalabra = "perro"
        posicion = posicionPerro
    End If
End If

' Si buscarPrimeraPalabra todavía está vacía, buscar "gato" en el texto
posicionGato = InStr(texto, "gato")
If posicionGato > 0 Then
    If buscarPrimeraPalabra = "" Or (posicionGato < posicion And posicionGato > 0) Then
        buscarPrimeraPalabra = "gato"
        posicion = posicionGato
    End If
End If

' Si buscarPrimeraPalabra todavía está vacía, buscar "liebre" en el texto
posicionLiebre = InStr(texto, "liebre")
If posicionLiebre > 0 Then
    If buscarPrimeraPalabra = "" Or (posicionLiebre < posicion And posicionLiebre > 0) Then
        buscarPrimeraPalabra = "liebre"
        posicion = posicionLiebre
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Despues en una celda le pasas la función **buscarPrimeraPalabra(CELDA)** y con esto obtendrias un resultado.
[image: Resultado en Excel]

Comment: La acabo de probar BRUTAL funciona a la perfeccion bro muchas gracias

Comment: Me da gusto saber que te ayudo, solo como observación complementa tu pregunta con codigo o formula en Excel que intentaste realizar esto nos ayuda a darnos una idea en lo que haz avanzado y quizas donde tengas el error. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver este problema, primero debes recorrer la columna de texto en busca de las palabras "perro", "gato" y "liebre". Esto se puede hacer utilizando un ciclo for para iterar sobre cada una de las celdas de la columna, y luego utilizando la función "InStr" para buscar en cada celda si se encuentra alguna de las palabras deseadas.

Una vez que se encuentre una de las palabras, se puede utilizar la función "InStr" de nuevo para buscar la posición de la palabra en la cadena de texto, y luego comparar esta posición con la posición de las otras palabras. La palabra que se encuentre en la posición más baja será la que apareció primero en la cadena de texto.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código en VBA recorre una columna de texto en busca de las palabras "perro", "gato" y "liebre", y luego encuentra la que apareció primero en la cadena de texto:

```
Sub encontrar_palabra()

' Declarar variables
Dim celda As Range
Dim texto As String
Dim pos_perro As Integer
Dim pos_gato As Integer
Dim pos_liebre As Integer

' Inicializar variables
pos_perro = 0
pos_gato = 0
pos_liebre = 0

' Recorrer la columna de texto
For Each celda In Range("A1:A10")
    
    ' Obtener el texto de la celda
    texto = celda.Value
    
    ' Buscar la palabra "perro" en el texto
    If InStr(texto, "perro") > 0 Then
```